# How do I write a piecewise Differential Equation in Julia?

Tags: julia, differentialequations.jl

I am new to Julia, I would like to solve this system:

[image]

where k1 and k2 are constant parameters. However, I=0 when y,0 or Ky otherwise, where k is a constant value.

I followed the tutorial about ODE. The question is, how to solve this piecewise differential equation in DifferentialEquations.jl?

Answer (score 1):

Answered on the OP's cross post on [Julia Discourse](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/piecewise-differential-equations/12187/6); copied here for completeness.

Here is a (mildly) interesting example $x''+x'+x=\pm p_1$ where the sign of $p_1$ changes when a switching manifold is encountered at $x=p_2$. To make things more interesting, consider hysteresis in the switching manifold such that $p_2\mapsto -p_2$ whenever the switching manifold is crossed.

The code is relatively straightforward; the StaticArrays/SVector/MVector can be ignored, they are only for speed.

```
using OrdinaryDiffEq
using StaticArrays

f(x, p, t) = SVector(x[2], -x[2]-x[1]+p[1])  # x'' + x' + x = ±p₁
h(u, t, integrator) = u[1]-integrator.p[2]  # switching surface x = ±p₂;
g(integrator) = (integrator.p .= -integrator.p)  # impact map (p₁, p₂) = -(p₁, p₂)

prob = ODEProblem(f,  # RHS
                  SVector(0.0, 1.0),  # initial value
                  (0.0, 100.0),  # time interval
                  MVector(1.0, 1.0))  # parameters
cb = ContinuousCallback(h, g)
sol = solve(prob, Vern6(), callback=cb, dtmax=0.1)
```

Then plot `sol[2,:]` against `sol[1,:]` to see the phase plane - a nice non-smooth limit cycle in this case.

Note that if you try to use interpolation of the resulting solution (i.e., `sol(t)`) you need to be very careful around the points that have a discontinuous derivative as the interpolant goes a little awry. That's why I've used `dtmax=0.1` to get a smoother solution output in this case. (I'm probably not using the most appropriate integrator either but it's the one that I was using in a previous piece of code that I copied-and-pasted.)